# Redirecting some sub pages to another format page using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to add `301` redirects to specific type subpage on my site which is hosted on LAMP server.

for example,

```
example.com/witcher-3-100309/player-count  - example.com/witcher-3-100309?tab=player-count
example.com/dota-2-100209/player-count  - example.com/dota-2-100209?tab=player-count
example.com/pubg-300100/player-count  - example.com/pubg-300100?tab=player-count
```

Is there any way in htaccess to write a general rule for all these type URLs to redirect correctly instead of individual `301` redirect codes in htaccess.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+\?=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ %{REQUEST_URI}?tab=%1 [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect `/foobar/?q=value` to `/foobar/?tab=value` .

When you sure the rule is working ok you can change the `R` (Temp Redirect flag) to `R=301` to make the redirection permanent.

Comment: Thanks, @starkeen for your reply. But this htaccess code is not working for me.I have the following in my httaccess,RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: My requirement is like, i need to redirect my url ,/ark-evolved-103882/player-count should redirect to /ark-evolved-103882?tab=player-count.Thanks

Comment: @ulman My rule should be at the top of your htaccess (before other rewriting rules) otherwise your other rules may override it.